# Rails Route not working despite link being correct and route appearing in "rake routes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there are a number of related questions on SO but none have matched by specific issue.

When I run rake routes, I get a list of routes as usual. I have corresponding urls that link directly to those specific route but when I click those links I get a routing error. When I hover over the links, however, the url seems to be correct and matching the exact route that appeared in rake routes. I am pretty lost on how to proceed from here.

Thanks for any help!

For your information, the routes of note are as follows:

```
approve_app_content PUT    /apps/:app_id/contents/:id/approve(.:format)           {:action=>"approve", :controller=>"contents"}
reject_app_content PUT    /apps/:app_id/contents/:id/reject(.:format)             {:action=>"reject", :controller=>"contents"}
 app_content GET    /apps/:app_id/contents/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contents"}
PUT    /apps/:app_id/contents/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"contents"}
```

The url matches the GET request exactly and still does not work:

/apps/buyers/contents/8234023 -- is the url I am using

Comment: Would you show us the routes.rb and the urls? And did you check the supported methods (post, get, etc.)?

Comment: can you post a link code ?

Comment: Post the code for your routes file, the links, and the exact error message(s). More detail will expedite an answer!

Comment: Are the other routes to ContentsController working?

Comment: app_content GET    /apps/:app_id/contents/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contents"}    doesnt match /apps/buyers/contents/8234023     it should be something like /apps/1001/contents/8234023

Comment: Here is the routes file: https://gist.github.com/Julian25/5886371

Comment: Here is the link: 

link_to t("general.actions.#{ action }"), [action, @app, item], :method => :put, :remote => true, :class => 'status'

Comment: A quick update that might provide some crucial information:

First of all we are using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails version 3.0.20.

Second of all the param :app_id actually refers to the app name - in the example given "buyers" is the app name and params[:app_id]. All of our routes are working except for the ones I posted above. No error messages are being generated other than the ones that inform us that the route is not found. We are having a difficult time with this and really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating a nested resource for two models

app model and content model. right?

Here's for show something like `/apps/101010/contents/90909090`

```
<%= link_to 'Show', app_content_path(@app, content) %>
```

On controller following like this:

```
def show
 @content = @app.content.find(params[:id])
end
```

Read this for [creating-nested-resources](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080)

Comment: This is how the content is being found:

"@content = @app.items.find params[:id]"

Comment: items are just data that is associated with an app. @content stores all of those that match a particular param.